# Proper way to simulate bouncing in libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to find a good way to simulate bouncing in my 3D program. Here is how I am trying to do it: I am saying if the position.y < the limit (which is -5) then bounce back up. Here is the code

```
        if(position.y > LIMITS.y)
            velocity.y += Main.GRAVITY/ 1000;
        else{
            velocity.y = -velocity.y / 1.5f;
            System.out.println(true);
        }
```

However, the bouncing sometimes works and sometimes stops very short, if anyone knows why this is happening and can help me improve this I would be extremely appreciative.

Comment: @pvg thats the purpose but it won't do that, it jumps less and less but then just stops even though it still has above 5 velocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think what you mean by stops very short is it is bouncing well then randomly stops at the bottom. This could be because the object goes more than 50% of it's distance that it will travel the next frame below the LIMIT of y. So the way to combat it is to reset the y position to its position before it went below.

```
else {
    position.y -= velocity.y; // reset to position before going under
    velocity.y = -velocity.y / 1.5f; // then adjust the velocity
    System.out.println(true);
}
```